# What media player application can remember where you last paused/stopped the track?

Tags: audio, media-player, audiobook

And that, even after closing the app.  A friend of mine is looking for that functionality to be used when listening to audio books.

[Update] He's on Windows (Vista -- but something for XP will do, I guess?), BTW.

Comment: Which OS are you looking for?

Comment: Windows, please.  :)

Comment: Great answers so far.  I'm giving my friend some time to test these and see what he'll stick with.  :)

Comment: I am looking for the same on Debian Gnu/Linux.

Comment: For Gnu/Linux see https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/4057/771

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Winamp](http://www.winamp.com/) has such a feature, if you install a plugin, called [Winamp Essentials](http://www.winamp.com/plugin/winamp-essentials-pack-v5-55/150126):

> This is a pack of plug-ins by the
>   people who work on Winamp. We can't
>   live without these plug-ins and now
>   you won't have to either. We will
>   update this pack for each major Winamp
>   release.
>
> Included in Winamp Essentials
>   5.55 are: Ogg Vorbis Encoder,Apple Lossless (alac) Decoder, FLAKE
>   Encoder, WavPack Decoder, Waveform
>   Wrapper, Lite-n Winamp Preferences, ML
>   Enqueue & Play, **Time Restore &
>   Autoplay**, Skins in Submenu, Playlist
>   Undo, Find File On Disk, Predixis
>   Removal tool and Playlist Sidecar for
>   Modern Skin. Please note you must have
>   Winamp version 5.55 or above to use
>   this plug-in pack.

Comment: My friend settled for Winamp plus the Winamp Essentials plugin.  :)

Comment: Glad to know I could be of help :)

Comment: @NikkiErwinRamirez Thanks for the post, however, it did not work for me. Whenever I double click on a playlist it plays from the first track, not from the last track that had been playing. Is there any options I should change? BTW, I use the latest versions by Mar 2022. Winamp 5.8 and Essentials 5.6.

Answer (score 3):

On Windows such application is [GOM Player](http://www.gomlab.com/eng/GMP_download.html). It is turned off by default so you would need to enable it first.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is iTunes.

You need to set the mp3's "Media Kind" to audiobook from within iTunes. (Rightclick track -> "Get Info"->"Options tab"). Then it will remember what you have listened to and how far into a track you are.

Answer (score 2):

[foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/) of course, with the option "Resume playback after restarting foobar2000" (in the playback section of the preferences)

And if you want more control over it, you could use the [bookmarks component](http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/index.php?showtopic=46612&hl=) -
Features:

- Bookmark via playlist contextmenu/keyboard shortcut/toolbar button
- Remove bookmark via contextmenu/Delete key
- Clear bookmarks via contextmenu/Edit menu/keyboard shortcut
- Inline editable Comment column
- Auto Mode: bookmark is automatically updated on stop, user starting another bookmark or nonbookmark, and on shutdown; if playback reaches the end of the track, the bookmark is automatically deleted
- Auto-bookmark playing track on user starting another track in different/same playlist, and on shutdown
- Capture playlist content when bookmarking
- Field for global title formatting: %bookmarks%
- Bookmark playback queue via Playback menu/keyboard shortcut/toolbar button
- Auto-bookmark playback queue on user stopping playback/starting another track, on shutting down, and on loading bookmarked playback queue items
- Instant Save: save bookmarks data file whenever listview data changes except when a column is clicked
- contextmenu Save: save bookmarks data file

Answer (score 1):

I might say [SongBird](http://www.songbirdnest.com/) which have an option (or an extension) to do that. (http://addons.songbirdnest.com/addon/1433).

Songbird is cross-platform (workgin on Windows, OS X, Linux, ..).